# Can I have stereo music playback during an iPhone call?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, call, sound-volume

Is there a way to playback (true) stereo audio (with seperate left and right channel) files during a phone call?

I'm not trying to make the callee hearing any of the stuff playing on my phone. I just try to playback a song while being on the phone (headset plugged in).

It seems that the iPhone switches to some kind of "joint stereo" mode, where it mixes L and R channel into a single one while the call is taking place.

Is there some option to prevent the iPhone from doing so? Is there an alternative music player for iOS that will render stereo audio as intended?

Comment: So you want to keep listening to your music while being on a call?

Comment: This is what I already do (from time to time). But it's summing the musics stereo channels while during a call.

Comment: If you could explain better how you accomplish play of music and a phone call, it might help someone propose a better solution. As most of us know, audio content fades out by design when you a) get a call b) place a call c) use siri d) several other items so it's not clear how you modified things from the standard behavior on iOS.